# paste multiple lines string to CMD or Bash variables

Tags: command-line, bash, string

I want to copy multiple lines (splitted by Enter key) from, for example, notepad and then paste it into new variable in CMD or Bash console and after that do some operations on it.

Although it's quite easy in PowerShell (I simply type

> variable_name="

then paste copied lines and simply add

> "

at the end) in predecessor it's much more complicated since CMD interpret each enter as "execute".
Is there any other way to accomplish it, instead of save as external text file?

Comment: cmd and bash are fundamentally different here...it might be better to split the question, because I'd bet for bash it's enough to escape (with a backslash) the linebreaks.

Comment: Bash console should work the same way as PowerShell. I'd just use `'` instead of `"` to avoid expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix each line with a `\` to indicate multiple lines. Answered on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6713056/114147) (although it probably doesn't even belong there.)